# Invalid atom feed generated

Tags: bug, rss

The current rss feed for the `ocaml` tag on stackoverflow is currently marked as invalid by most rss readers that I've tried. According to W3C's feed validator, the culprit is the text from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25656748), and more specifically the following line:

```
order of writing them may differ. seteq: &#39;a set -&gt; &#39;a set -&gt; bool &lt;/p&gt;
```

Apparently, there is an unescaped unicode character (Vertical Tabulation) between the `f` and the `e` of `differ` which confuses feed readers. I'm not sure where this character comes from, but shouldn't this be sanitized at some point?

> [image: screenshot of question]

Comment: Upon adding my screenshot, it seems something (my browser?) sanitized the `differ` text in your post. Could you re-add it?

Comment: @Stijn Unfortunately, it looks like this is also the case here, but your screenshot makes the issue very clear.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have fixed the offending question, and taken a snapshot to work on locally to see if we can fix the underlying problem.

Comment: Thanks, the feed is indeed back to normal in my reader and accepted by W3C's validator.